# Get first pixel (0,0) of image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, pixel, rgba

I need get only first pixels `(0,0)` of image with jquery (RGBA or HEX)

pls help me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to draw the image in a canvas element. Then you can use the `getImageData` method to return an array containing RGBA values.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'image.jpg';
var context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
data = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
```